# Load ScriptResourceDefinition JQuery on every page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5

This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467942/how-do-i-make-scriptresourcedefinition-load-on-all-pages-instead-of-automaticall), but nobody responded, so I ask again as I feel it is important.

Unobtrusive validation for web forms works great, **but**, only when validation controls are added to a form.  For other pages that lack validation controls, no reference to the JQuery file is rendered.

I currently use JQuery on all pages, so reference it manually in a Master page file,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when I access a page with my own JQuery logic **and** validation controls, then two references get created (my own, plus ASP.Net's `ScriptResourceDefinition`).

How can I achieve one of the following:

1. Let `ScriptResourceDefinition` know that the file exists and has already been added?
2. Force `ScriptResourceDefinition` to render JQuery on *every* page regardless of whether it detects validation controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628170/792888

The answer is to inherit from ScriptManager and stop ASP.Net's built-in behaviour of creating the unnecessary (duplicate) JQuery link

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication46
{
    public class CustomScriptManager : ScriptManager
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.PreRenderComplete += Page_PreRenderComplete;
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var jqueryReferences = Scripts.Where(s => s.Name.Equals("jquery", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            if (jqueryReferences.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove the jquery references as we're rendering it manually in the master page <head>
                foreach (var reference in jqueryReferences)
                {
                    Scripts.Remove(reference);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In web.config this is wired up to replace the standard ScriptManager:

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <tagMapping>
      <add tagType="System.Web.UI.ScriptManager" mappedTagType="WebApplication46.CustomScriptManager" />
    </tagMapping>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```